# Grub efi won't boot windows 10 installed as legacy

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, bios, grub-legacy

I installed Ubuntu 18.0.4.4 on my laptop which already has Windows 10 installed, on it.  It uses an mbr partition table.
During installation I created an efi partition for Ubuntu to boot  and I had a successful install. After installation  grub boots directly into Ubuntu and I can't find the windows option, I realized that I installed Ubuntu in efi mode which is incompatible with my windows 10 that is  installed as legacy also Ubuntu efi partition is  not in the same location with my  windows so it has only Ubuntu efi files on it. I found my way through by repairing windows boot manager, also to boot into  windows mode I disable uefi support form bios leaving only legacy os enabled and I enable uefi again to boot into  Ubuntu. I stayed on windows for over 25hrs after this I try going  back to Ubuntu and  I got a grub rescue.
**"The problem is not the grub rescue"** because when I fix grub it won't still be able to locate windows again making me repeat the previous steps over and over again. How do I make grub boot  both of them correctly. I don't want to re-install any of my  os again but I have their installation disk with me.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu in efi.

Comment: Is it still possible to make grub boot into bios?

Comment: I understand you Sir. I've read some of this but I think the problem is been switched. It's my windows that uses legacy and Ubuntu efi . Because my windows uses legacy support and not uefi grub doesn't find it when it loads and therefore boots directly into ubuntu  I want grub to recognize my windows os. I can't be modifying my bios options anytime I want. Windows or Ubuntu

Comment: If grub can't find windows and there's no fix am I left with the option of tampering with my bios

Comment: This is seems okay. Thank you.